# React / Graphql / Apollo, Not refetch data after update states and change routes

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I have a graphql query that shows me a list of users, when I update the list with a mutation, the state change well, but when I change my route and I come back to the old one, it return the old state.I have to do a hard refresh on my browser to have the new list.

This is my query :

```
export const group = (id) => {
  const  data  =  Client.query({
    query:  gql`
    query group($id: Int) {
      group(_id: $id) {
        _id 
        name
        lat
        lng
        is_private
        creation_date
      }
    }
  })
```

This is my component :

```
async componentWillMount() {
  try {
    var data = await group(632);
    var result = data.data.group[0];
    this.setState({
      group: result
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

updateGroup = async() => {
  try {
    var data = await groupUpdate(501, 632, {
      name: this.state.group.name,
      is_private: this.state.group.is_private,
      address: this.state.group.address,
      creation_date: this.state.group.creation_date,
      nbrEmployees: this.state.group.nbrEmployees
    });
    notifyUser(NOTIFY.success, "Done");
    this.toggleInfo();
  } catch (e) {
    notifyUser(NOTIFY.error, "Error Serveur");
  }
}
```

Any help please ?

Comment: Do you think your query is cached? That's the reason may be its returning same data. If that's the case try with `fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'`

Comment: Thank your for the response, but fetchPolicy: 'no-cache' didn't work.

Comment: I think the problem comes from apollo-boost, because when i update manually my database and refetch data with my query , new data not appear only when i hard refresh te browser

Comment: Fixed with defaultOptions like that ==>
     
     const defaultOptions = {
      query: {
        fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
        errorPolicy: 'all',
      },
    }
   Client.defaultOptions = defaultOptions;
It was the fetchPolicy . thank you @PardeepDhingra